# Сохранять ссылки в gridView

Tags: java, android, gridview

При добавлении элементов(ссылок) в список `recyclerView`,элементы добавляются в `mItems` адаптера, то есть ссылки будут автоматически сохранены -  в RecyclerView.

Но в GridView такая тема не катит, подскажите пожалуйста как сохранять добавленные элементы(ссылки)? 
Вопрос возможно очень простой, но очень завис на нём.

Или еще проще интерпретация вопроса:

Как сохранять ссылки, которые я добавляю в список?

Answer (score 2):

RecyclerView ничего сам не хранит. Его задача интерпретировать одинаковым способом любые view использующих адаптеры. Ссылки, которые Вы добавляете в список необходимо сохранять в источнике данных который использует адаптер, если их время жизни примерно равно времени жизни Activity. В ином случае сохраняйте их в БД или файл и обновляйте после этого источник данных адаптера.

Comment: как возможно правильно сохранять в источнике данных? можно чуточку поподробней (конкретно интересует для gridView) можно прямо ссылками в меня кидать)

Comment: gridView в данном случае вторичен..почитайте вот тут.. для начала думаю хватит https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Comment: controlList.get(position).getImageUploads().add(url); таким образом я могу сохранить ссылку?

Comment: Вам нужно реализовать модель данных в виде класса в котором в том числе можно прописать метод сохранения ссылки. Сработает ли предложенное Вами сохранение данных зависит от вашей модели